# How to overlap button on mask in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve the following effect in React Native:

[image]

After using the code below, mask would appear and is what I want.

But I found that the button disappear.

It seems like the button would covered by the mask.

How to modify the code to let button would not covered by the mask?

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
import { Svg, Defs, Rect, Mask, Circle } from 'react-native-svg';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
});

const CircleMask = () => {
  return (
    <Svg height="100%" width="100%">
      <Defs>
        <Mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
          <Rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#fff" />
          <Circle r="30%" cx="50%" cy="35%" fill="black"/>
        </Mask>
      </Defs>
      <Rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0" />
    </Svg>
  );
};

const PendingView = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Waiting</Text>
  </View>
);
const CameraScreen = (params) => {
  const takePicture = async (camera) => {
    const options = {
      quality: 0.85,
    };
    await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNCamera style={styles.preview}>
        <CircleMask />
        {({ camera, status }) => {
          if (status !== 'READY') return <PendingView />;
          return (
            <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => takePicture(camera)} style={styles.capture}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      </RNCamera>
    </View>
  );
};
export default CameraScreen;
```

Before add mask:

[image]

After add mask, button disappear.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use style absolute for your container and then add  pointerEvents="none" on your circle comnponenet to be able to click on it